# What is the role of the Magnesium Ion in Chlorophyll

Tags: photochemistry

Chlorophyll as the main photoreceptor molecule in photosynthesis seems to have three unique features 1) a lot of conjugated double bonds, 2) a ring like structure and 3) a central metal ion (Mg).  The conjugated double bonds make sense, as this creates delocalized electrons, resulting in excitation energies in the optical spectrum, which allows the molecule to absorb light.  The ring-like structure seems to be designed to chelate the central Mg ion, but what is the role of the Mg ion? Does it add electrons to the delocalized molecular orbital.  Its interesting that pheophytin, the next step in the redox chain,  seems to be identical to chlorophyll except it doesn't have the Mg ion.  Is this something like electron doping in a semiconductor PN junction biasing the flow of electrons towards the pheophytin?

Comment: I am no expert in the field, I'm not sure what you are referring to as the *"redox chain"*. Is it photosynthesis? (I can be dumb sometimes, hope I can excused :)

Comment: Besides CSE article, you may find some info [here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12206396/) as well.